# I want to use Google Analytics cross domain tracking, does it only work with anchor tags?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, cross-domain, gtag.js

I'm using gtag.js and I navigated to click event. The URL does not contain the client ID.
Does cross domain tracking work only with anchor tags?

Comment: Can you please provide the definition of the click event and the URL? Thank you.

Comment: When the result of my search is navigate to another domain, it is said that the GA CLIENT ID is inserted into the query string and sent. If an anchor tag is used, it is included in the query string, but if a click event is used, it is not included in the query string. @damianesteban

Comment: - Click Event

`const click = () => {
    location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64111978/i-want-to-use-google-analytics-cross-domain-tracking-does-it-only-work-with-anc";
};`

`<div onClick={click}>
  MyQuestion
</div>`


- URL

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64111978/i-want-to-use-google-analytics-cross-domain-tracking-does-it-only-work-with-anc?_ga=GA_CLIENT_ID

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

If the clientid is not in querystring then there is something in the configuration that is not right and cross-domain will not work. The clientid in the URL is used to keep the same value (_ga cookie) in the next domain, if this value is not present Google Analytics code cannot know it and will generate a new one, so the user will be seen as a different user.